# If no divs in a selection have a class then do something?

Tags: jquery

With jQuery how can I run a function if no divs in a selection have a certain class?

There are multiple div.result. Initially they will all have a class of "hidden" but in time none of them will. Im running the following on different events:

```
  if (!$(".result").hasClass("hidden")) {
    $("body").addClass("all-shown");
  }
```

Comment: `$("body").toggleClass("all-shown", $(".result.hidden").length === 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of the returned set...

```
if (!$(".result.hidden").length) {
    $("body").addClass("all-shown");
}
```

Example...

```js
if (!$(".result.hidden").length) {
    alert("no items");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```